# python equivalent of DataView(originalSize.buffer).getUint32(0, true);?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, cryptojs, pycrypto

I have an array `[ 16 125   7   0   0   0   0   0]` which is a uint8 array(unsigned 8bit integer array).

I want to convert this to a little endian number.

The javascript function to do this is `size = new DataView(originalSize.buffer).getUint32(0, true);`

but i want the similar method in python.

The desired output is `490768`.

Is it possible to do this in python?

Answer (score 0):

In python, you use the [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) module for this kind of stuff:

```
>>> import struct
>>> a = [16, 125, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> struct.unpack('<q', bytearray(a))
(490768,)
```

Comment: works like a charm but how do you get the first tuple only? that is `490768`. i want only this

Comment: @ShaunMenezes: `unpack` always returns a tuple, so you have to `result, = ...unpack` (note the comma) or `result = ...unpack(..)[0]`